# How to access $_POST value from an external jquery file?

Tags: javascript, php

I am not great at Jquery and PHP I was coding in a way that sometimes I needed my javascript variables to get php post values something like that.

```
var articleCategoryA2 = '<?php if(isset($_POST['A2']))echo $_POST['A2'];?>';
```

When I was done with the coding I wanted to get everything organized I decided to have a javascript code in one single file, but it won't interact with the embeded php code in it after I include the javascript code in the php file that gets the post values

What should I do? For being noob I haven't got a clue.

Comment: well I have a php file that gets post values from a form, and I have a piece of jquery code that gets this post value by the comand I used above, and it was working, but I tried to do the same instead of having my jquery code inside of the php file I decided to have a .js file that would do the same, but it doesn't recognize the comand above

Answer (score 3):

Javascript files won't be compiled by php so if you need a php variable passed in you need to put it in a separate script tag

```
<script>
  var articleCategoryA2 = '<?php if(isset($_POST['A2']))echo $_POST['A2'];?>';
</script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

Now the variable is available in `app.js`.

Comment: When I want to get the php post value I can but the jquery code has to be inside of the same php file which is getting the post values through a form, the problem is to make the very same jquery code to work in the same way in a .js with the pieces of php code inside of it and then included in the main php file which gets the post values throgh the form

Comment: Wow...what post value? Question doesn't mention any form being posted or how it gets posted. Problem is not at all clear or well defined

Comment: well I have a php file that gets post values from a form, and I have a piece of jquery code that gets this post value by the comand I used above, and it was working, but I tried to do the same instead of having my jquery code inside of the php file I decided to have a .js file that would do the same, but it doesn't recognize the comand above.

Comment: Sounds like a fundamental design flaw if the above will not work for you. I recommend this answer as the way to go.

Comment: Then something else is wrong but you haven't provided enough code. Check the page source to see what is actually being printed

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to initialize the variable in JavaScript, then conditionally assign the value of that variable.

So in your JavaScript file:

```
var articleCategoryA2; //defined, but null
```

...then inline within your PHP file:

```
<?php    
    if(isset($_POST['A2'])){
        /* if $_POST['A2'] is set, put its value into the JavaScript variable articleCategoryA2 */
        echo('            
            <script>                
                articleCategoryA2='.$_POST['A2'].';                
            </script>            
        ');        
    };    
?>
```

If `$_POST['A2']` exists, JavaScript will set its value into `articleCategoryA2`.